# sfDoctrineGuardPlugin windows 2008 401 unauthorized

Tags: windows, iis-7, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I have a Symfony 1.4 app working on Linux using `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin`. Everything's fine. I am porting this to W2008 MSSQL and am really close BUT cannot get past the 401 Unauthorized error.
The app starts up at frontend_dev.php and then because i'm not logged in, redirects to the plugin. I then get this in the symfony log:

```
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfBasicSecurityFilter} Action "default/login" requires authentication, forwarding to "sfGuardAuth/signin"
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfFilterChain} Executing filter "sfRenderingFilter"
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfFilterChain} Executing filter "sfGuardRememberMeFilter"
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfFilterChain} Executing filter "sfExecutionFilter"
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfGuardAuthActions} Call "sfGuardAuthActions->executeSignin()"
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfPHPView} Render "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/appFROMGMCSAPP/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/templates/signinSuccess.php"
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfPartialView} Render "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/appFROMGMCSAPP/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/templates/_signin_form.php"
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfPHPView} Decorate content with "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\appFROMGMCSAPP\apps\frontend\templates/layout.php"
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfPHPView} Render "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\appFROMGMCSAPP\apps\frontend\templates/layout.php"
Feb 16 11:05:34 symfony [info] {sfWebResponse} Send status "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"
```

I guess I can add error_log statements into the `executeSignin`.. maybe my DB is not accessible even though the tables look ok ??

Comment: I added an error_log("IN executeSignin") followed by a die(); in BasesfGuardAuthActions but all I get in the log is                                    Feb 16 12:06:44 symfony [info] {sfGuardAuthActions} Call "sfGuardAuthActions->executeSignin()" ie. no DEBUG..

Answer (score 1):

This *bug* on IIS has been fixed last year: http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/4557

Can you check that you have an up to date version of symfony & sfDoctrineGuardPlugin? Also, check if you don't have extended the signin action inside your app, where the 401 status can still be.